# Google cloud console secret version

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-secret-manager

I want to replace a string value in my secret store for a cloud function.

The only way appears to add a new secret, however even after destroying the original string (version1) the new secret remains version 2, and my function doesn't work

Is there a way of making the new secret version 1 or is there another workaround

thanks